# php $_session return

Tags: php

I got an ajax submitting form source code, and learning it right, I found the return errors are all in a big square. I want to separate errors to where they belong to. 
then I can simply add something like following code

```
 <?php if($_session('errorarray'): ?>
   <span class="errorclass"><?php echo $errorarray['phone']; ?></span>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

here is validation php code, (I have 5 items need to be checked)

```
 $error = array();

    if(!check('name'))
        $error[]='too short!';
    else if(validate_name($_POST['name']))
        $error[]='letters please!'; 

    ..........


if(checkphone($_POST['phone'])){
    $error[]="Please enter a valid phone number";
}
```

here is the code return to $_Session

```
if(count($error))
{
    if($_POST['ajax'])
    {
        echo '-1';
    }

    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
    {
        **$_SESSION['errorarray'] = array ($error);** // possible? 
        $_SESSION['post']=$_POST;

        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

    exit;
}
```

Sorry I am very new to php. Hope my expression is not too hard to understand.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set `$_SESSION['errorarray'] = $error;` Then in your view, you can do something like `<span class="errorclass"><?php foreach ($_SESSION['errorarray'] as $err) { echo $err; } ?></span>`

Sorry, your question is a bit unclear, if you provide more details we could probably give you a better answer.